# ¿Si hay muchas personas que se llaman Jesús juntas, cómo debo designarlas?

Tags: gramática, plurales, sustantivos

¿Si hay muchas personas que se llaman Jesús juntas, cómo debo designarlas?

- *Eran varios Jesús a la vez*
- *Eran varios Jesúes <sup>[Jesuses (!) ]</sup> a la vez*

Me parece que no es como *Paco* o *Pepe*.

- Muchos Pacos; muchos Pepes.

Aún que Pepe sea el padre de Jesús, no creo que sea lo mismo...

La motivación de esta pregunta es a raíz de [esta que hice en WordPress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/74278/12615). Es respecto al plural de WP, pero la respuesta que me pareció acertada tenía esta yema (énfasis mía):

> WordPress is a [singular without plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Singulars_without_plurals). A second instance would be a [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) that could not use the same name, because the name *WordPress* [is a trademark](http://ma.tt/2010/09/wordpress-trademark/) of the [WordPress Foundation](http://wordpressfoundation.org/).
>
> ***Like Jesus, just more rules.***

Comment: It's really a good question for Chistianity.SE, as in this case it's not just the formation of the plural involved, but the use of the plural against the singular. You may see this question as "how to form the plural in words ending in s".

Comment: Por cierto, si sabes castellano, preferimos que se hagan las preguntas en ese idioma, lo puedes consultar en el [FAQ]. ;)

Comment: @JoulSauron, mil perdones, en WordPress SE estoy siempre dando la lata de que lean el FAQ y no lo hice aquí... Do.it.now! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo correcto es decir

> Eran varios **Jesuses** a la vez.

La formación del plural en este caso no es distinta de otros sustantivos. Como referencia puedes tomar el artículo del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas [Reglas de Formación del Plural](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=plural). El sustantivo (nombre propio) Jesús cae en la regla `f)` de dicho artículo.

> f) **Sustantivos y adjetivos terminados en -s o en -x**. Si son monosílabos o polisílabos agudos, forman el plural añadiendo -es: tos, pl. toses; vals, pl. valses, fax, pl. faxes; compás, pl. compases; francés, pl. franceses. En el resto de los casos, permanecen invariables: crisis, pl. crisis; tórax, pl. tórax; fórceps, pl. fórceps. Es excepción a esta regla la palabra dux, que, aun siendo monosílaba, es invariable en plural: los dux. También permanecen invariables los polisílabos agudos cuando se trata de voces compuestas cuyo segundo elemento es ya un plural: ciempiés, pl. ciempiés (no ciempieses); buscapiés, pl. buscapiés (no buscapieses), pasapurés, pl. pasapurés (no pasapureses).

Comment: Sin embargo, la pregunta no es tanto sobre la formación del plural, si no sobre este caso particular de Jesús, que era varios al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Pero *Jesús* no estaría en el último caso? Y luego la wiki no contempla el caso de nombres propios...

Comment: @Joul creo que no comprendo tu punto.

Comment: @brasofilo los nombres propios **son** sustantivos y no tienen ninguna regla especial. Y no cae en el último caso, pues este es de palabras compuestas donde la segunda ya es plural. Jesús es una única palabra (en singular), como sería el caso de francés => franceses o compás => compases.

Comment: @jachguate Que puede ser que en este caso no sea algo del castellano (cómo formar el plural), si no algo propio de la visión cristiana, es posible que prefieran decir "varios 'Jesús' a la vez", en singular, es lo que entiendo yo que pregunta.

Comment: @Joul creo que en ese caso la pregunta estaría en el sitio equivocado. Para un creyente, en todo caso, supongo que en Español no sería distinto de otro idioma, así que la pregunta bien vale para [CSE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Por otro lado, en este sitio, creo que debemos mantenernos en la línea de las reglas del idioma, con independencia de las creencias de cada uno.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para aclarar la implicación religiosa. Creo que mi primera versión ha sido ambigua. Pero es que el nombre **tiene** esa carga. En Brasil, suena bastante raro cuando aparece alguien llamado así, es como si el nombre fuera reservado para una persona no más. Pero, al grano: si se puede intercambiar "Tomás" y "Jesús" en la frase, tenemos una regla clara. Y si no, porque?

Comment: Vale, entendido, entonces esta respuesta es la correcta, en mi opinión :)

Comment: @JoulSauron y jachguate, a titulo de encerramiento, una amiga ha levantado el tema en el [foro Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer.asp?vId=174795), y hay información extra bien interesante. Saludos y gracias!

Comment: @jachguate solo como una sugerencia, yo preferiría que pusieras como referencia una fuente algo más confiable; la Wiki, en este caso, simplemente transcribe lo que dice el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas en el literal f) de [`esta entrada sobre el plural`](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i). Te sugeriría que uses el DPD como referencia y no la Wiki (que, no en este caso concreto, pero sí muchísimas veces deja mucho que desear como fuente de referencia).

Comment: @Gonzalo lo tendré en cuenta, en realidad hice una búsqueda en google y puse la primera referencia que encontré, pero tendré presente buscar en el diccionario en una próxima. :)

Comment: @Gonzalo-Medina de hecho, la entrada sobre el plural de la Wikipedia ha sido borrada por violación de copyright, por lo que ahora apunta a una página vacía. No lo edito yo mismo en la respuesta porque llevo poco tiempo participando y no sé si debo o está mal visto.

Comment: @guillem, en general en los sitios de StackExchange, es bien visto que hagas ediciones (hay medallas por eso), siempre que las mismas sean de buena calidad, corrijan problemas o añadan valor a las preguntas o respuestas originales.

En este caso, he editado yo mismo el artículo.  En el futuro, si estas seguro del valor de tu edición, no te quedes con las ganas de hacerla.

Un saludo.

Comment: @guillem Gracias por notar el problema con el enlace. Como te ha dicho, jachguate, siéntete en completa libertad de editar mis respuestas (si se trata de una adición/corrección valiosa); yo casi no visito este sitio ya, así que no hay problema.

Comment: Para mi sonaría un poco raro que alguien diga Jesuses para referirse a muchas personas llamadas Jesús, simplemente dices:
"Hay muchos Jesús en mi escuela" no "Hay muchos Jesuses en mi escuela",
"Conozco a muchos Carlos" no "Conozco a muchos carloses"

Answer (score 2):

En el uso del idioma lo más apropiado (nótese que no digo *correcto*, si la base de la pregunta es de origen religioso, este no es el lugar para contestarla) es decir ***Hay varios hombres llamados Jesús***. Por supuesto se puede decir ***Encontré a varios Jesuses allí*** ya que **Jesus** es un **substantivo** y se rige por las normas de ortografía del español sobre [plurales](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i) y [concordancia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5). pero es un uso despectivo del idioma.