# ¿Cómo se pluralizan los nombres propios?

Tags: gramática, plurales

A veces leemos frases del tipo

> Hacen falta muchos Gandhis en el mundo

Refiriéndose a que hace falta mucha gente como Gandhi para que tal o cual cosa suceda. Por la construcción de la palabra se usa el plural del nombre, por lo que en lugar de Gandhi decimos *Gandhis*.

Sin embargo, si esa persona que usamos como referente tiene nombre y apellido, no sé cómo debe pluralizarse su nombre. Si por ejemplo esa persona se llama Juan Romero, ¿cuál es correcto de entre estos? ¿O acaso es otra la forma correcta?

> Hacen falta muchos Juanes Romero
>
> Hacen falta muchos Juan Romeros

¿Y si se trata de un nombre compuesto como por ejemplo Juan Antonio Romero? ¿Es esto correcto?

> Hacen falta muchos Juanes Antonio(s?) Romero

¿Y si nos referimos a más de una persona como por ejemplo [Zipi y Zape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipi_y_Zape)?

> Tanto Juan y José como Ramón y Rodrigo eran los Zipis y Zapes de
>   nuestro colegio

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [Plural de "Jesús"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3111/5481)

Answer (score 9):

Extraído de las [reglas del plural de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i):

> Regla 2.8. **Nombres propios**. Puesto que los nombres propios, a
>   diferencia de los comunes, no designan clases de seres, sino que
>   sirven para identificar un solo ser de entre los de su clase, no
>   suelen emplearse en plural. Sin embargo, al existir seres que
>   comparten el mismo nombre propio, sí cabe usar este en plural para
>   designar varios referentes: Los Javieres que conozco son todos muy
>   simpáticos; En América hay dos Córdobas, una en la Argentina y otra en
>   México. Al respecto, conviene tener en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> a) Los nombres de pila hacen el plural de acuerdo con las reglas
>   generales (→ 1): las Pilares, las Cármenes, los Pablos, los Raúles,
>   los Andreses.
>
> b) Los apellidos se mantienen invariables cuando designan a los
>   miembros de una misma familia: Mañana cenamos en casa de los García;
>   Los Alcover se han ido a vivir a Quito. Cuando se emplean para
>   designar un conjunto diverso de individuos que tienen el mismo
>   apellido, el uso vacila entre mantenerlos invariables o añadirles las
>   marcas propias del plural de acuerdo con su forma. La tendencia
>   mayoritaria es mantenerlos invariables, sobre todo en el caso de
>   apellidos que pueden ser también nombres de pila, para distinguir
>   ambos usos: Los Alonsos de mi clase son muy simpáticos (nombre de
>   pila) y Los Alonso de mi clase son muy simpáticos (apellido); o cuando
>   se trata de apellidos que tienen variantes con -s y sin -s, como
>   Torre(s), Puente(s) o Fuente(s): En mi pueblo hay muchos Puente (gente
>   apellidada Puente) y En mi pueblo hay muchos Puentes (gente apellidada
>   Puentes). Salvo en estos casos, los que terminan en vocal admiten con
>   más naturalidad las marcas de plural que los que acaban en consonante:
>   En la guía telefónica hay muchísimos Garcías (pero también hay
>   muchísimos García), frente a ¿Cuántos Pimentel conoces? (más normal
>   que ¿Cuántos Pimenteles conoces?). Los apellidos que acaban en -z se
>   mantienen siempre invariables: los Hernández, los Díez.
>
> c) Los nombres de dinastías o de familias notorias también vacilan. La
>   mayoría tienden a permanecer invariables: los Habsburgo, los
>   Trastámara, los Tudor, los Borgia; pero otros se usan casi siempre con
>   marcas de plural: los Borbones, los Austrias, los Capuletos.
>
> d) Cuando se usa una marca comercial para designar varios objetos
>   fabricados por dicha marca, si el nombre termina en vocal, suele
>   usarse con la terminación -s característica del plural, mientras que,
>   si termina en consonante, tiende a permanecer invariable: Hay tres
>   Yamahas aparcadas en la puerta; Los Opel tienen un motor muy
>   resistente. Lo mismo ocurre con los nombres de empresas, cuando
>   designan varios de sus establecimientos: Últimamente han abierto
>   muchos Zaras en el extranjero; Hay dos Benetton en Salamanca. Si el
>   nombre es compuesto, permanece invariable: Los nuevos Corte Inglés de
>   la ciudad son muy grandes.

Comment: Interesante información, gracias por encontrar lo que la RAE indica. Sigo con la duda de cómo decir cuando se trata de un nombre compuesto.

Answer (score 6):

Esto es lo que dice sobre el tema el *Manual* de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* (Espasa, 2010). Es una gramática bastante descriptiva más que prescriptiva, así que no dicta reglas de pluralización sino que cuenta más o menos lo que pasa:

> **3.2.2a**     Se espera, en principio, que los nombres propios no tengan plural. Lo forman, sin embargo, cuando se asimilan (en mayor o menor
>   medida) a los comunes (§ 12.5.2c). Siguen entonces las reglas de
>   estos, como en *las celestinas*, *los donjuanes*, *las magdalenas*,
>   *los quijotes*, o en *Nunca más volverá a haber en Nicaragua **Adolfos** Díaz, **Emilianos** Chamorro, **José Marías** Moncada, **Anastasios** Somoza en el poder* (Ramírez, *Alba*). Con los nombres compuestos, la pauta más común es la que muestra el ejemplo citado con
>   *José María*, esto es, que solo se pluralice el segundo componente. Aun así, se documentan excepciones: *Pero así serán y han sido todas
>   las doñas **Marías Antonias** del Universo* (Villalonga, *Bearn*). Las
>   formas de tratamiento *santo*, *santa* y *doña* suelen recibir plural;
>   quedan invariables, en cambio, *san*, *don*, *fray*, *sor*:
>
> > Tuvo la audacia de privar de mi presencia a la negra imagen de las **Santas** Marías del Mar_ (Mujica Lainez, *Escarabajo*); Estaban los Pepes y las Pepas del Padul, los Josés y las Josefas de Dúrcal, los
> >     **Don** Josés y **Doñas** Josefas de Órgiva (Alarcón, *Alpujarra*); Lo que va de la poesía de Garcilaso a la de Góngora, eso va de la prosa
> >     de Valdés y de los dos **fray Luises** a la de Quevedo (Alatorre,
> >     *1001*).
>
> [...]
>
> **3.2.2b**     En el plural de los sustantivos que designan apellidos suelen alternar la forma invariable y la adición de *-s*, esta última
>   más frecuente si se trata de dinastías: *Que yo sepa **los Fierro**,
>   **los Oriol**, **los Urquijo**, tenían millones antes de la guerra* (Cabal, *Briones*); *No debí haber deshonrado la sangre de **los
>   Borbones*** (Fuentes, *Región*). También predomina la forma con marca
>   de plural si el que habla no desea hacer referencia a un conjunto de
>   personas que comparten cierto apellido, sino (a menudo
>   despectivamente) a varias que se asemejan en algo a una que sí lo
>   lleva: *Pues ¿cómo me ha de doblegar del ayuno el padre Escobar, ni
>   juntos todos **los Escobares** abogados con todos sus libros?* (Santa
>   Cruz Espejo, *Luciano*). Por otras razones, tampoco toman *-s* los
>   sustantivos que terminan en esta consonante o en *-z* (*los Borges*,
>   *los Rodríguez*, *los Solís*, *los Vélez*), ni los que coinciden con nombres comunes o adjetivos (*los Castillo*, *los Leal*, *los León*,
>   *los Mayor*).

---

De acuerdo al texto que copié, si no lo entendí mal, *Juanes Romero, Juan Antonios Romero* o *Juanes Antonios Romero* (excepcionalmente), *Zipis y Zapes*.

Comment: ¡Gracias por contestar! Así pues, ¿cómo deberían decirse los casos que planteo en la pregunta?

Comment: De acuerdo al texto que copié, si no lo entendí mal,  _Juanes Romero_, _Juan Antonios Romero_ o _Juanes Antonios Romero_ (excepcionalmente), _Zipis y Zapes_.

Answer (score 1):

Si termina en vocal, se agrega una letra ***S*** al final.

> *"Di eso a los dos Diegos..."*
>
> *"Las dueñas de ese perro son las tres Marías..."*

Si termina en consonante, se agrega ***"es"*** si masculino, o neutro:

> *Los Ezequieles por un lado, los demás por el otro...* (Ezequiel).
>
> *"vosotras, Soledades, son del equipo A"...*

Pero algo muy curioso, es que los nombres terminados en consonante, especialmente son procedentes de otros idiomas, aveces adaptados al español:

*Isabel* - Isabela

*Ruth*

*Edith*

*Judith*

*Abigail*

*Beatriz*

*Lourdes*

---

No es casual oír a la gente decir "Abigailas", o "Abigailes", generalmente se tiende a usar más palabras como en el siguiente ejemplo:

> *"Ellas dos son vecinas, ambas se llaman Beatriz..."*
>
> *"Me encantan las dos chicas llamadas Ruth, ambas son muy bonitas..."*

---

"Juan Antonio Romero" sería: "Los Juan Antonios Romero".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Lobo-Eze. Nótese que mi pregunta contiene también cuestiones sobre nombres con apellidos y nombres compuestos.

Comment: Disculpa. no lo note jeje, En el caso de los nombres compuestos como el caso de ***"Juan Antonio Romero"***, seria: ***"Los Juan Antonios Romero"***, igual no lo pongo como respuesta, ya que de esto no estoy seguro.

En el caso de los apellidos, no se modifican, solo siguen como están, sea plural o singular. Saludos.

Comment: O sea, que se pluraliza como cualquier otra palabra.