# Pluralizando nombres de estaciones, parques, etc

Tags: gramática, plurales, nombres-propios

Digamos que haya dos estaciones en una ciudad, **Primera Estación** y **Segunda Estación**. ¿Sería correcto pluralizar los nombres en la siguiente manera?

> "Hay un punto entre las llamadas **Primera y Segunda Estaciones**..."

¿O no sería acceptable ya que se trata de lo que equivale a un apellido y en castellano no se pluralizan los apellidos, solo sus artículos?

¿O quizá no deberías mayuscular «Estaciones»?

Comment: Me parece que en esos casos "Estaciones" perdería la mayúscula: *un punto en las estaciones Primera y Segunda*, o se diría: *un punto entre la Primera y la Segunda Estación*.

Comment: relacionado: [¿Cómo se pluralizan los nombres propios?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15082/5481)

Comment: Coincido con @Gustavson. Además, díría que lo estrictamente correcto sería decir entre la Primera Estación y la Segunda Estación, ya que son nombres de lugares (como por ejemplo entre Madrid y Buenos Aires).

Comment: Ciudad, ¿ donde ?

Answer (score 1):

Es muy raro que una estación lleve "Estación" en su nombre, tal como lo indicas. Lo más común es que se anteponga el nombre común "estación", por ejemplo: la estación Primera. En este caso estación no es parte del nombre propio, es un nombre común. Y  tu oración sería así:

> "Hay un punto entre las estaciones Primera y Segunda"

Veo redundante poner "llamadas", ya que al estar en mayúscula la primera letra se entiende que esos son los nombres propios. Además, estaciones no llevaría mayúscula por no ser un nombre propio

Pero, si fuera parte del nombre "Estación Primera", entonces no se puede pluralizar porque no comparten el mismo nombre completo.

> "Hay un punto entre "Estación Primera" y "Estación Segunda"

Aunque lo anterior no es muy común.

https://www.diccionariodedudas.com/nombre-propio-y-nombre-comun/

Answer (score 0):

Introduzco una reflexión para orientar la respuesta. Yo lo pensaría con otro ejemplo de genéricos: montes, ríos y rías. Pero aún así cada caso sería dependiente de su calidad y la de los topónimos:

Asunción está entre los montes Chimborazo y Veleta (o los que sean).
Roma está entre las colinas X e Y.
Huelva está entre los ríos Guadiana y Guadalquivir.
Córdoba (Argentina) está entre Río(s) Cuarto y (Río) Tercero.
Cangas está entre las rías de Vigo y Pontevedra (nótese el DE).

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.